# function that accepts *[128]uint8, *[256]uint8 etc

Tags: go

In my code I have :

```
fmt.Printf("event.Comm type: %T\n", event.Comm)
fmt.Printf("&event.Comm type: %T\n", &event.Comm)
```

Which prints:

```
event.Comm type: [128]uint8
&event.Comm type: *[128]uint8
event.Comm type: [256]uint8
&event.Comm type: *[256]uint8
```

and so on.

I would like to define a function where I can pass their pointers, and get some work done.

so I defined:

```
func aux(x *[]byte){
        fmt.Println("Aux got", x)
}
```

hoping that I'd send `aux(&event.Comm)` and `aux(&trigger.Comm)` et al.

Except that it refused to build:
`cannot use &event.Comm (type *[128]byte) as type *[]byte in argument to aux`

What's the idiomatic way to define a function signature with `*[n]uint8` as its arguments?

Comment: How is it that `event.Comm` has type `[128]uint8` in the first 2 printed lines, and type `[256]uint8` in the last 2 printed lines? Are you changing the definition of whatever type `event` is between runs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idiomatic approach is to use a [slice](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types):

```
func aux(x []byte){
        fmt.Println("Aux got", x)
}
```

Use the [slice expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions) `[:]` to create a slice backed by the array:

```
 aux(event.Comm[:])
```

Note that [arrays](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/6) and [slices](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/7) are different types and are not assignable to each other. Arrays have a fixed size. A slice describes a section of an array.  A slice header contains a pointer to the backing array, the length of the slice and the capacity of the backing array.

Answer (score 3):

`[128]byte` is an array type. `[]byte` is a slice type. They aren't the same type and there's no implicit conversion from one to the other. Your sample code doesn't make it clear what `aux` is actually supposed to do, but at a guess you should change `aux` to accept a `[]byte` (pointers to slices are hardly ever necessary), and call it like `aux(event.Comm[:])`. `[:]` is a [slice expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions) which creates a slice with a view of the whole array.

Answer (score 0):

The type of the event is fixed sized array of `[128]byte` but in the argument of the aux you are passing the slice. The error was explaining the issue pretty well. In order to solve the error you need to define the size of the slice so your code should be like this.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func aux(x *[128]byte) {
    fmt.Println("Aux got", x)
}
func main() {
    var Comm [128]uint8
    aux(&Comm)
}
```

or you can convert the array type to slice as hobbs explained in his answer.